# Is it possible to download from link file from a web directory?

Tags: files, filesystems, apache-httpd, symlink

Suppose there is an instance of **apache** whose web directory is:

```
/var/www/html
```

Is it possible to create a link from a file in a distinct directory so that a web user can download that file using the link?

For example,

```
cd /home/user
echo "test" > test.txt
sudo ln -s test.txt /var/www/html/test.txt
```

When I browser the web directory, the link file is not shown.

Why?

My goal is to create a unique URL for each file (which does not necessarily have to be unique), per download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable the symlink in your Apache config file (`FollowSymLinks`): https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options